# .NET equivalent Java tools and libraries

Tags: java, .net, libraries

So I am pretty much been a Java programmer but I play with F# on the weekends.
One of hardest part I have with .NET is trying to find the equivalent to some tool or library I had in Java.

Sure I can google the equivalent for each tools but I would rather see a side by side equivalent for each tool in one place. I also would like to know which one is the preferred or generally most popular equivalent tool/library.

Here is what I have so far:

**Java ====> .NET**

*IDE:*
Eclipse ===> Visual Studio

*Continuous Integration:*
Hudson ===> Not Sure.

*Command line build:*
Maven and Ant ===> NAnt and Bylan I think?

*XML Serialization:*
JAXB ==> Some .NET native stuff

*JSON Serialiation*
SF JSON-LIB ==> ???

*ORM:*
Hibernate ==> LINQ or NHibernate

*Dependency Injection:*
Spring and Guice ===> I think there is .NET Spring

*Servlet Container or Webserver:*
Tomcat,Jetty, so many ===> Tell me there is more than just IIS..

*Unit Testing Framework:*
JUnit, TestNG ==> I think NUnit and XUnit

*Mocking libraries:*
Mockito,JMock,EasyMock ===> ???

*GUI:*
Swing ==> Win Forms I think???

*AOP:*
AspectJ ==> Looks like you have to pay for something expensive.

Comment: This would be better suited as a Community Wiki I believe.

Comment: WCF also has a self-hosted option, so you're not stuck with IIS, even without going to 3rd-party solutions.

Comment: @swilliams yep probably should be. My bad.

Comment: @swilliams and @Support - multilanguage SO  How dio convert this to a community wiki post?

Comment: @Support - multilanguage SO I have played with Scala but I want to play with F# because 
 1. I know OCaml
 2. Scala syntax is just enough like Java that is causes some cognitive dissonance
 3. I want to learn the .NET platform.

Comment: I think a mod has to turn it to a community wiki, or it needs to be edited a few times. Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it at this point :)

Answer (score 3):

Mocking ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-mocking-framework-to-use

Continuous Integration ==> [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)

JSON Serialization ==> [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

GUI == > [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) (different than Swing but nice)

Web Server hooks ==> [Mod_Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono)

Comment: Ah, I was gonna point out DataContractJsonSerializer.  Don't forget Json.Net @ http://json.codeplex.com/ - which I think its owner has proven to be faster.  +1 for SO link to Mocking discussion.

Comment: Hudson works fine with .NET too, calling in to msbuild to do compiles.

Answer (score 2):

Let me fill a couple of those:

Continuous Integration: Hudson ===> CruiseControl + MSBuild

ORM: Hibernate ==> Entity Framework or NHibernate

Dependency Injection: Spring and Guice ===> Castle

Unit Testing Framework: JUnit, TestNG ==> NUnit and XUnit, VS2010 comes with it's own testing framework, MSTest

Mocking libraries: Mockito,JMock,EasyMock ===> Moq

GUI: Swing ==> WinForms

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You will really want to look at [Microsoft Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) for mocking. I quite liked moq but not being able to mock static methods was a deal-breaker. There were some commercial mocking frameworks that provided the full functionality I was accustomed to in Java, but Moles is free.

Answer (score 1):

> Dependency Injection: Spring and Guice
>   ===> I think there is .NET Spring

Yes, there is.  There's also Microsoft Unity and Enterprise Framework 4.0.

> Unit Testing Framework: JUnit, TestNG
>   ==> I think NUnit and XUnit

And FitNesse.

Comment: DI: And also Autofac and Ninject